# Process Builder Error: Owner:Queue.DeveloperName is causing an Error

Tags: process-builder, queue

I keep on getting this error for our process builder whenever I add the variable [Case].Owner:Queue.DeveloperName into the Criteria.

Basically, the PB will check if the Owner of the Case does not belong to a Queue, will not proceed to perform any actions. If it does belong to a Queue, then it will do some actions.

However, when I try to create manually a Case, then I get this error:

**Error element myDecision (FlowDecision).
The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Owner:Queue.DeveloperName because it hasn't been set or assigned.**

The criteria of the PB is just this:

**Field:**
[Case].Owner:Queue.DeveloperName

**Operator:**
Is null

**Type:**
Boolean

**Value:**
False

Any help is much appreciated. I've been stuck on this issue since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the same in the criteria. **Select Formula Evaluated  to true** and use below formula

```
LEFT([Case].OwnerId,3) = '00G'
```

using the above formula it will check if the Case Owner is Queue If yes then it will perform the associated action.

Comment: oh nice, this is a good solution. thanks. I will check this one out later. But again, thanks for this quick answer. XD